# Wordpress change media url

Tags: wordpress, image, path

I moved my blog from /staging/ to the root directory. Everything's fine except the images are still pointing to the folder on /staging/ so are broken. The images are in the root, if I type the direct path without /staging/ they show fine. Things I've checked:

```
Settings > WordPress Address (URL)
Settings > Site Address (URL)
Settings > Permalink Settings
phpMyAdmin > wp_options > siteurl
phpMyAdmin > wp_options > home
```

Anyone have any advice on where else I can check that might have those images set to /staging/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Better Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin after migrating a site from staging to production. It lets you search database WordPress database tables for the old domain and replace it with the new one. It lets you select which tables you want to search and replace. I usually select all tables. It also lets you do a test run, so that you can see how many occurrences you have before doing an actual replace. Take a backup of the database before you do an actual replace, just to be safe. Also be careful of trailing slashes - they must be exactly same in both the search string and the replace string.

```
Search for:
stagingdomain.com or localhost (whatever your staging site used)
Replace with:
productiondomain.com
```